# Radio Button Checked not checking

Tags: html, xhtml, forms

I am having a problem with the following code:

```
<div>
<span>Item 1</span>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1" checked="checked" />
</div>

<div>
<span>Item 2</span>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" class="checkbox" id="radio2" />
</div>
```

I have added checked="checked" to the first checkbox but the one checked is the second one for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the code you posted, something in the missing code must be wronge. I put your code in a jsfiddle ([1](http://jsfiddle.net/pub_philipp/b38CG/)) and it works like a charm.

According to w3schools, `checked="checked"` is correct (http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_checked.asp). I often use `<input type="radio" "name="foo" checked />`, which also works.

More infos about the site would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
Radio inputs must be inside of a form for 'checked' to work.
<form>
<div>
<span>Item 1</span>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1" checked>
</div>

<div>
<span>Item 2</span>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" class="checkbox" id="radio2">
</div>
</form>
```